# How to split ZipInputStream into Inputstreams

Tags: java

i get file from ftp server and parse it to some java class

```
 wrapper.connect();
            byte[] archiveBytes = wrapper.retrieveFileBytes("some path");
            try (ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(archiveBytes))) {
                ZipEntry entry;
                while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                    byte[] fileBytes = FileUtils.readZipEntry(zis);
                    if (fileBytes.length == 0) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    try (InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileBytes)) {
                        var model =  ftpFileReader.read(inputStream);
                       
                        domains.add(model);
                    } 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return domains;
    }
```

and util method

```
 public static byte[] readZipEntry(ZipInputStream zis) throws IOException {
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int count;
            while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) > -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            return outputStream.toByteArray();
        } finally {
            zis.closeEntry();
    

}
}
```

everything works good on my local PC with windows, but if i deploy it on server i got

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back
```

dont understand what is going wrong and how to fix i. Please help

ps. stacktrace

[image]

```
org.springframework.retry.RetryException: Non-skippable exception in recoverer while processing; nested exception is java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor$2.recover(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:299) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar!/:4.3.7]
        at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.handleRetryExhausted(RetryTemplate.java:539) ~[spring-retry-1.3.3.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:387) ~[spring-retry-1.3.3.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:255) ~[spring-retry-1.3.3.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.BatchRetryTemplate.execute(BatchRetryTemplate.java:217) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar!/:4.3.7]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.transform(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:308) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar!/:4.3.7]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:210) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar!/:4.3.7]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:77) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar!/:4.3.7]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar!/:4.3.7]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar!/:4.3.7]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar!/:4.3.7]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar!/:4.3.7]
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.7.jar!/:4.3.7]
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.7.jar!/:4.3.7]
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.7.jar!/:4.3.7]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar!/:4.3.7]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar!/:4.3.7]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:152) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar!/:4.3.7]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:68) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar!/:4.3.7]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:68) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar!/:4.3.7]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar!/:4.3.7]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar!/:4.3.7]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:139) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar!/:4.3.7]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:320) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar!/:4.3.7]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:149) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar!/:4.3.7]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back
        at java.base/java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.closeEntry(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at ftp.utils.FileUtils.readZipEntry(FileUtils.java:18)
```

Comment: Are there no clues in the remainder of the stacktrace? Is this ZipException the root cause, or caused by some other exception? And where is this exception thrown? The stack trace would tell you (or us, if you included the relevant part) all that.

Comment: add pic with stacktrace

Comment: The ZIP file your server reads is corrupted. Or, possibly, 'corrupted' - zip is a container format with a billion variations, but there is a standard 'just choose these for it to be universally readable zip file' - and it isn't one of those.

Comment: Vary strange , if it corrupted why i dnt have any trable with read it on my PC.  And how to fix that?

Comment: "i get file from **ftp server**" - the typical issue is ascii mode transfer.

Comment: i retrieve not file but byte[] using FtpClient.retirievFileBytes(path to file). How to fix it Andey?

Comment: `FtpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE)`

Comment: not working - FtpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE) set it when connect to Ftp and still get this exception

Comment: Use some tool to get a hash/checksum of the file on each computer and make sure it's the same. If your server is on Linux, you probably have a tool such as `md5sum`/`sha1sum`/`sha256sum` (e.g. in [Debian's coreutils](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/coreutils)) that you can run from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found solution
before retrieve every file i put this function

```
ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

and then

```
InputStream inputStream = ftp.retrieveFileStream(path)
```

and everything going good at local PC and server with linux